# Primefaces add treenode in database

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.0 and I create a TreeNode draggable (as example detailed in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/dragdrop.xhtml).

I would like update my tree node in my database but I don't understand as do it.

My actual solution is as first to remove from database TreeNode and after to add new TreeNode built by user. 
Every item in my TreeNode is a custom object, so by getRowKey() method I can build new tree index.

Is this best way?

Thanks.